# Finding the Minimum Value

Tags: statistics

Consider the top 15% of people are accepted into a program. If exam scores are normally distributed with a mean of 70 and a standard deviation of 4.8, what minimum score you can achieve to score into the top 15%?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you show what you yourself think is a way to tackle this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: +1 sigma covers 84.1%, believe 85% needs to be covered?

Comment: +1 sigma covers 68 % for normal distributed variables. +2 sigma covers 95 percent. The exact result will have to be found using error-function.

Comment: Would min. value be 74.975?

Comment: I don't know, but I might be able to tell if you are right if you right down how you get it.

Comment: i know i have to look at the 85% but other than that I'm not sure. Using the normal distribution table

Answer (score 0):

The equation you are interested in is the following:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^M N e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} = 0.85,
$$
where $N$ is a normalization such that the result of the integral is $1$ when $M\rightarrow \infty$, $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the average. Using Mathematica, I have found $M$ to be equal to 
$$
M=74.97488
$$
It means that $85\%$ of the results are below $M$, which one can also find using the normal distribution table, as you have done yourself.